# Currency value is converting to integer from LWC to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforce-id, currency, decimal

Passing the below object from LWC to APEX Method, in this `Payment_Received__c` value is 10.50, when i read this value in Apex method its print `10`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "10618",     
        "Id": "a0B4W000016LrTQUA0",         
        "Payment_Received__c": "10.50"
    }
]
```

Apex Method

```
  public static void updateInvoices(List<Invoice__c> paidInvoices){
        
        for(SCInvoice__c psi : paidInvoices){
            system.debug('psi.Payment_Received__c -->' + psi.Payment_Received__c);
            //here its printing 10
            
        }
        
    }
```

`Payment_Received__c`  this is the currency filed in invoice object with Currency(16, 2).

Can anyone help me what i am missing here

Comment: Looking at the JSON it seems that `Payment_Received__c` is a string in the LWC. If so, before passing the array to the APEX methos, convert it to a number: `records.forEach((record) => { record.Payment_Received__c = +record.Payment_Received__c; })`